# Restrict fields in TFS

Tags: tfs-2015

Is there a way I can restrict a field in TFS for the creator of the ticket once the ticket reached a particular status? For example I have created ticket 123 in TFS and the assignee of the ticket set it to In Progress status. I as the requester should not be able to edit the Issue Description field since the ticket is already being worked on by the assignee.

Comment: You should use convention and agreement to achieve this rather than validation and control.

Comment: By means of convention and agreement do you mean I need to develop a code that would create this functionality?

Comment: No, I mean talking to people and getting acceptance of the right way to deal with things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to limit access to a different specific user per work item state.

You can add limited for a Group or Individual for a particular state, but it would always be the same individual.

If this problem is not rife then you can simply add a notification for the creator when the work item changes, you can for to the bits that you want, and have users self police.